# Delete elements in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a string containing html elements, now I need to select some elements and remove them from the string.
In JQuery I tried the following:

```
html_string = "<ul><li data-delete>A<li><li>B</li></ul>";
html_clean_string = $(html_string).remove('[data-delete]').html();
```

This is what I expected:

```
"<ul><li>B</li></ul>"
```

But I got the same original string. So how can I use CSS selectors to remove html elements from a string?

Comment: `html_string = "<ul><li data-delete>A<li><li>B</li></ul>;` you did not close off your string properly. try  adding a `"` before the semicolon

Comment: Yes I didn't noticed. I just wrote it on the browser, this is not the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var html_string = "<ul><li data-delete>A</li><li>B</li></ul>";
var elems = $(html_string);
elems.find('[data-delete]').remove();
var html_clean_string = elems[0].outerHTML;
```

You had a couple of issues:

1. `.remove()` only operates on the elements in the jQuery object, not on child object so you have to `.find()` the appropriate child elements before you can remove them.
2. Since you want the host top level HTML too, you will need the `.outerHTML`.
3. You had mistakes in your html_string.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/x8ra6efz/

---

You can also save a little jQuery with more chaining like this:

```
var html_string = "<ul><li data-delete>A</li><li>B</li></ul>";
var html_clean_string = $(html_string).find('[data-delete]').remove().end()[0].outerHTML;
```

Working jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wmtascxf/